# ¿Por que no puedo hacer If en PhP?

Tags: php

quiero saber entender por que sto no me funciona:

```
   <?php
        $result == NULL;
        $Panel_Avanzado == 'Panel_Avanzado';
        if ($result == $Panel_Avanzado) 
        { 
        print 'Existe' 
        } 
        else 
        { 
        print 'No existe' 
        } 

?>
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

***Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 7***

Comment: if ($result == $Panel_Avanzado) { print 'Existe' } else { print  'No existe' } parentesis, puntos y comas de mas

Comment: Si lo queres achicar lo podes hacer asi ($result == Panel_Avanzado) ? Print 'Existe' : Print 'No existe';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El resultado al quieres llegar me parece que es:

```
$result = NULL;
$Panel_Avanzado = 'Panel_Avanzado';
if ($result == $Panel_Avanzado) 
{ 
   print 'Existe';
} 
else 
{ 
   print 'No existe';
}
```

Notar que cada sentencia debe terminar con punto y coma.
Además, las asignaciones se deben hacer con un solo =.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente es erroneo:

```
IF 
    ($result)==($Panel_Avanzado);
{
```

en su lugar pon:

```
if ($result == $Panel_Avanzado)
{
```

El error esta en los parentesis.

PHP puede imprimir con `print`, pero se recomienda usar `echo` en su lugar, ya que `print` depende de cierta configuración por la que puede funcionar en un servidor y no en otro.